# PHP insert query gives syntax error but still writes into database

Tags: php, insert, syntax-error

A query executes and writes into a database table and the field data is fetched and displayed in a WHILE loop so basically it works but I get a php error :

> Error Inserting!You Have An Error In Your Sql Syntax; Check The Manual That Corresponds To Your Mysql Server Version For The Right Syntax To Use Near \'1\' At Line 1

With line 1 being

```
<?php
```

I have tried playing around with commas and colons but I cannot get rid of the error. This is the query.

```
$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
$user = $_SESSION['UserName'];

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO films VALUES ('0', '".($user)."','".($formValue["subject"])."',NOW(),'".($usercomments)."','".($formValue["rating"])."','action')");

if(mysql_query ($query, $Link)){
$message = "Thank you for your comments";
header("Location: films.php?message=$message");
}else{
$message = "Error Inserting!" . mysql_error();
header("Location: films.php?message=$message");
```

Comment: Your fascination with `ucwords()` eludes me. Your problem however, line 1 is **not** the opening PHP tag, I presume it's the query line. Firstly, remove all of those brackets around your variables

Comment: ucwords() you mean capitals?

Comment: I thought that's how everyone did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO films VALUES ('0', '$user','$formValue[subject]',NOW(),'$usercomments','$formValue[rating]','action')";
```

This may simplify the code and solve your error.

Comment: I hate seeing arrays being embedded into quoted strings like that.

Comment: Didn't work. The error has to be the insert query? It cannot be other code?

Comment: Why dont you try printing out the query and see what it looks like?
exit("INSERT INTO films VALUES ('0', '".($user)."','".($formValue["subject"])."',NOW(),'".($usercomments)."','".($formValue["rating"])."','action')");

Comment: As stated the data writes into the table so it works but there must be a syntax error somewhere or maybe there's an issue with the rest of the loop. I have updated the opening post to show it. This is what exit outputs :

INSERT INTO films VALUES ('0', 'admin','exit',NOW(),'what does this do','','action')

Comment: query should be string not Boolean or integer